# TStringList load memorystream? <Delphi>

Tags: delphi, stream

edited :

My file has several lines. I encrypt the file onto a new file. I want to store each line of decrypted file (=a stream) into StringList.

First, I have a file contain :

```
aa
bb
cc
```

I encrypt the file with this function :

```
procedure EnDecryptFile(pathin, pathout: string; Chave: Word) ;
 var
   InMS, OutMS: TMemoryStream;
   cnt: Integer;
   C: byte;
 begin
   InMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
   OutMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     InMS.LoadFromFile(pathin) ;
     InMS.Position := 0;
     for cnt := 0 to InMS.Size - 1 do
       begin
         InMS.Read(C, 1) ;
         C := (C xor not (ord(chave shr cnt))) ;
         OutMS.Write(C, 1) ;
       end;
     OutMS.SaveToFile(pathout) ;
   finally
     InMS.Free;
     OutMS.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

My purpose now is to store original value of each line into StringList. I don't want to store decrypted file into harddisk, so I use stream.

This is the function to decrypt the file into stream :

```
procedure DecryptFile(pathin: string; buff: TMemoryStream; Chave: Word);
var
  InMS: TMemoryStream;
  cnt: Integer;
  C: byte;
begin
  InMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    InMS.LoadFromFile(pathin);
    InMS.Position := 0;
    for cnt := 0 to InMS.Size - 1 do
    begin
      InMS.Read(C, 1);
      C := (C xor not(ord(Chave shr cnt)));
      buff.Write(C, 1);
    end;
    // buff.SaveToFile('c:\temp\dump.txt') ;
  finally
    InMS.free;
  end;
end;
```

--

```
 bbuffer := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      DecryptFile(path, bbuffer, 10); //  
      //ShowMessage(IntToStr(bbuffer.size)); // output : 1000
      bbuffer.Position := 0;
      SL := TStringList.Create; 
      try
        SL.LoadFromStream(bbuffer);
        for I := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do // SL.Count = 1
        begin;
        //add each line of orginal file into SL??
        end;
      finally
        SL.free;
      end;
    finally
      bbuffer.free;
    end;
```

Comment: I tested your code with the testfile provided and everything works like it should. The stringlist contains 3 lines (aa, bb, cc) at the end of the encrypt/decrypt cycle. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to hide my face. Yes it works. I wonder why I got SL.Count=1 several hours ago. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load from stream takes a `TStream` so you can give it a `TFileStream` as well as an `TMemoryStream`. The code you posted should work without any problems. What exactly does not work?

You might have to use

```
bbuffer.Position := 0;
```

to reset the position to the start of the stream before loading it into the string list.

**EDIT:** You write single bytes to a stream and then try to load a string list from it. That won't work. The stream is just a collection of bytes. How should the string list know where one string ends and the next one starts? `TStringList.SaveToStream` writes separator bytes to the stream so that it can parse the string list back. So, you could do your encryption on the string list and then write the whole string list to the stream, then read the stringlist and do the decryption on the string list.

Comment: Now SL can load bbuffer but SL.Count is only 1. Before SL load bbuffer, I add "showmessage(inttostr(bbuffer.size));", it show not 1 item. ?? I am going to paste my code few minute again.

Comment: `bbuffer.size` is the number of bytes in the stream and not the number of strings. The stream does not know that you put strings in it, it's just bytes.

Comment: @user: SL.Count gives the number of lines, not the number of characters in the lines. if the string in your buffer does not contain line breaks, then a SL.Count of 1 is to be expected.

Comment: Okey, it show the size of the file. I updated my question to add the code.

Comment: @Smasher, Here's the story : I have a file contain several lines, then I encrypt the file. The code above to decrypt the encrypted file into stream. From stream, I want to store each decrypted line to StringList. I'll try to understand your edited post.

Comment: How do you generate the file? `TStringList.SaveToStream` and then encrypt?

Comment: I've updated the question. Now my question is not related with the title :( Sorry.

Comment: I think I have to encrypt each line of file and not the whole file then my problem will be solved :)